# Rest route patterns

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have defined '**customers/45**' and '**customers/recently-created**' routes as follows in express application and '**customers/recently-created**' does not invoke '**CustomerHandler.getRecentlyCreatedCustomers**' function. Insted of that it invoke '**CustomerHandler.findById**'. Please advise what is the best way to do this

Here is my code

```
router.prefix('/customers', (route) => {
    route.get('/', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.getAllCustomers);
    route.get('/:customerId', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.findById);
    route.get('/recently-created', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.getRecentlyCreatedCustomers);
    route.post('/', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.create);
    route.put('/:customerId', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.update);
    route.delete('/:customerId', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.delete);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try swapping the lines of your routes, so your code looks like:

```
router.prefix('/customers', (route) => {
    route.get('/', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.getAllCustomers);
    route.get('/recently-created', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.getRecentlyCreatedCustomers);
    route.get('/:customerId', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.findById);
    route.post('/', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.create);
    route.put('/:customerId', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.update);
    route.delete('/:customerId', auth.authorize, CustomerHandler.delete);
});
```